# Gridview Freezing/Fixed Header loses background color when scrolling

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, datagridview

I'm attempting to implement a freeze/fixed header pane to my gridview.  The gridview works fine as does rendering it into this solution.  When this page first renders the page looks perfect.  However, when I attempt to scroll the information the background color header bar scrolls up along with the rest of the data.  The only thing that is frozen is the text headers of the gridview but the background is transparent as the gridview scrolls.

I've included the important data of this page.  However, if more information needs to be added to the code below, please let me know.  I've attempted to add/tweak the javascript, css, gridview, and C# settings with no luck.  I'm stumped.

Note: This is for IE 9.

Page Template info...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Cosmetic.Wrapper.cs" Inherits="Cosmetic_Wrapper" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head runat="server">
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
       <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
      </asp:PlaceHolder>
 (other nonessential header garbage - If you really need this let me know)
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server"  ID="Header"
 <script src="path/to/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="path/to/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function CreateGridHeader(DataDiv, GridView1, HeaderDiv) {
         var DataDivObj = document.getElementById(DataDiv);
         var DataGridObj = document.getElementById(GridView1);
         var HeaderDivObj = document.getElementById(HeaderDiv);

         //********* Creating new table which contains the header row ***********
         var HeadertableObj = HeaderDivObj.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));

         DataDivObj.style.paddingTop = '0px';
         var DataDivWidth = DataDivObj.clientWidth;
         DataDivObj.style.width = '50000px';
         DataDivObj.style.width = '#507CD1';

         //********** Setting the style of Header Div as per the Data Div ************
         HeaderDivObj.className = DataDivObj.className;
         HeaderDivObj.style.cssText = DataDivObj.style.cssText;
         //**** Making the Header Div scrollable. *****
         HeaderDivObj.style.overflow = 'auto';
         //*** Hiding the horizontal scroll bar of Header Div ****
         HeaderDivObj.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
         //**** Hiding the vertical scroll bar of Header Div **** 
         HeaderDivObj.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
         HeaderDivObj.style.height = DataGridObj.rows[0].clientHeight + 'px';
         //**** Removing any border between Header Div and Data Div ****
         HeaderDivObj.style.borderBottomWidth = '0px';



         //********** Setting the style of Header Table as per the GridView ************
         HeadertableObj.className = DataGridObj.className;
         //**** Setting the Headertable css text as per the GridView css text 
         HeadertableObj.style.cssText = DataGridObj.style.cssText;
         HeadertableObj.border = '1px';
         HeadertableObj.rules = 'all';
         HeadertableObj.cellPadding = DataGridObj.cellPadding;
         HeadertableObj.cellSpacing = DataGridObj.cellSpacing;

         //********** Creating the new header row **********
         var Row = HeadertableObj.insertRow(0);
         Row.className = DataGridObj.rows[0].className;
         Row.style.cssText = DataGridObj.rows[0].style.cssText;
         Row.style.fontWeight = 'normal';



         //******** This loop will create each header cell *********
         for (var iCntr = 0; iCntr < DataGridObj.rows[0].cells.length; iCntr++) {
             var spanTag = Row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
             spanTag.innerHTML = DataGridObj.rows[0].cells[iCntr].innerHTML;
             var width = 0;
             //****** Setting the width of Header Cell **********
             if (spanTag.clientWidth > DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].clientWidth) {
                 width = spanTag.clientWidth;
             }
             else {
                 width = DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].clientWidth;
             }
             if (iCntr <= DataGridObj.rows[0].cells.length - 2) {
                 spanTag.style.width = width + 'px';
             }
             else {
                 spanTag.style.width = width + 20 + 'px';
             }
             DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].style.width = width + 'px';
         }
         var tableWidth = DataGridObj.clientWidth;
         //********* Hidding the original header of GridView *******
         DataGridObj.rows[0].style.display = 'none';
         //********* Setting the same width of all the componets **********
         HeaderDivObj.style.width = DataDivWidth + 'px';
         DataDivObj.style.width = DataDivWidth + 'px';
         DataGridObj.style.width = tableWidth + 'px';
         HeadertableObj.style.width = tableWidth + 20 + 'px';
         return false;
     }

     function Onscrollfnction() {
         var div = document.getElementById('DataDiv');
         var div2 = document.getElementById('HeaderDiv');
         //****** Scrolling HeaderDiv along with DataDiv ******
         div2.scrollLeft = div.scrollLeft;
         return false;
     }

</script>
 </head>
  <body>
 (Insert top portion of page cosmetics here)
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Path>
        <%--To learn more about bundling Path in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
        <%--Framework Path--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Path/To/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Path--%>

    </Path>
</asp:ScriptManager>
 <header>
   (More page cosmetics)
 </header>
 <div id="body">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedInfo" />
<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainBody" />
</section>
</div>
<footer>
 (nonessential footer info)
</footer>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP Page

```
<%@ Page Title="ASP Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Cosmetic.Wrapper" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="asp-page.aspx.cs" Inherits="asp_page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedInfo" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainBody" Runat="Server">

<style type="text/css">

    .GridViewStyle
    {    
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:11px;

        background-color: White; 
    }

    .GridViewHeaderStyle
    {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:15px;
        position:fixed;

        background-color:#507CD1;
        color:black;
        height:40px;

    }

</style>

  <%--Insert SQL Datasource info here --%>

       <div>
        <%--Div contains the new header of the GridView--%>
        <div id="HeaderDiv">

        </div>
              <%--Wrapper Div which will scroll the GridView--%>
        <div id="DataDiv" style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid olive; width: 2000px; height: 300px;" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="line" DataSourceID="SqlConn1"  ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">

        <columns>
        Place Bound/TemplateFields here
        </columns>


 <insert gridview cosmetic info here - if needed please let me know>
 </gridview>
 </div>
 </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class asp_page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "<script>CreateGridHeader('DataDiv', 'GridView1', 'HeaderDiv');</script>");
        }
    }
    protected void cmdClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "<script>CreateGridHeader('DataDiv', 'GridView1', 'HeaderDiv');</script>");
    }



}
```

**UPDATE - 2/27 - 10:16 PST**

**Here's the rendered code when entering it into a blank HTML page.  The C# page is not leveraged at all in this example.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
</title>
    <script src="path/to/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="path/to/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="test.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="Insert Millions of random characters here" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
    if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.form1;
    }
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
            theForm.submit();
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
</div>
    <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    var header = $("#GridView1").find("tr")[0];
                    $("#HeaderDiv").append(header);
                });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .GridViewStyle
        {    
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:11px;
            background-color: White; 
        }

        .GridViewHeaderStyle
        {
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:15px;
            background-color:#507CD1;
            color:black;
            height:40px;

        }
    </style>

    <br />
          <div>
            <div id="HeaderDiv">
            </div>
            <div id="DataDiv" style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid olive; width: 2000px; height: 300px;" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
    <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="GridView1" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="GridViewHeaderStyle">
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th class="GridViewHeaderStyle" scope="col" style="background-color:#507CD1;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column1&#39;)" style="color:#333333;"Column1*</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column2&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column2</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column3&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column3</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column4&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column4</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column5&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column5</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column6&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column6</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column7&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column7</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column8&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column8</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column9&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column9</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column10&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column10</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column11&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column11</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column12&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column12</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column13&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column13</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column14&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column14</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column15&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column15</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column16&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column16</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$Column17&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Column 17</a></th><th scope="col">>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
            <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Edit$0&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Edit</a></td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </td><td>Blah </td><td>Blah </td><td>Blah </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Blah </td><td>
                    <span id="GridView1_Label2_0">Blah </span>
                </td><td>Blah </td><td>
                    <span id="GridView1_Label3_0">Blah </span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="GridView1_Label4_0">Blah </span>
                </td><td>Blah </td><td>
                    <span id="GridView1_Label1_0">Blah </span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="GridView1_Label5_0">Blah </span>
                </td><td>Blah </td><td>Blah </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>
                    <span id="GridView1_Label6_0">Blah</span>
                </td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Edit$0&#39;)" style="color:#333333;">Blah </a></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: When the page first loads it's perfect.  The data from the Gridview pulls with no issues and the gridview sits inside of a scrollable box.  Also, the subject/column headers load perfectly.  The headers cosmetically look and are positioned perfectly (save for a quick font size adjustment).  The problem is that when you scroll the gridview down, the data along with the header background color scrolls up but the subject/column headers stay in place with a transparent background.  I'm trying to fill the frozen transparent background with a color.

Comment: Right, since CSS works on the client I need to see the HTML so I can see what the structure looks like. That will let me know what's happening. If you have a sample url it'll help find the issue.

Comment: Basically I have the code split into two parts.  The code and the cosmetic stuff that surrounds it.  I'll update the first post with this information.

Comment: @afzalulh Sorry this is IE 9.  Totally spaced on noting this.  My bad.

Comment: @AlexMorales Sorry I don't have a public URL too look at.

Comment: @TechieJoe, please award the bounty if one of these answers fixed your problem. There's only 6 hours left of the grace period

Comment: The problem still exists.

Comment: Please post the *rendered HTML*, that's the only way I can test the code for you.

Comment: Done.  Replaced the code at the bottom of the page with the rendered HTML.

Comment: @roryok I'll send you another 50 after we get this working.

Comment: I guess you got this working, haven't heard anything since february....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a line in your `CreateGridHeader` function which is applying your desired background color to the **width** of the `DataDivObj`

```
DataDivObj.style.width = '50000px';
DataDivObj.style.width = '#507CD1';
```

This is the same background colour used by the header

```
.GridViewHeaderStyle
{
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:15px;
    position:fixed;

    background-color:#507CD1;
    color:black;
    height:40px;
}
```

There must be a connection here. I think you might resolve the issue by changing the second `style.width` to `style.backgroundColor`

**UPDATE**

I see now that DataDiv is a fixed height, with overflow: auto. I missed this before. So you don't actually need to implement a scroll function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var header = $("#GridView1").find("tr")[0];
        $("#HeaderDiv").append($("<table id='floatingheader'>").append(header));
    });
</script>
```

This keeps it inside the fixed height div http://jsfiddle.net/QLWn2/

Comment: I adjusted this second width variable to 'backgroundColor' along with the change that @afzalulh provided in his answer.  And now two of these headers appear one on top of the other. One freezes as I want but the second contains the same behavior that I first noted in the first post of this thread.

Comment: Hi joe, please check out my second answer, it resolves your problem

Comment: Hi Joe, I've updated this answer. please let me know if it fixes your issue

Comment: Nope it didn't.  I posted the updated rendered HTML code at the end of the first post of this thread (below the update timestamp).  The behavior is that the header does not freeze.  Everything looks good after that.

Comment: Maybe we're getting our wires crossed. What exactly do you mean when you say "freeze"? can you link to an example of the desired behaviour on another site? I've given you an example of a grid with a header outside the fixed div (http://jsfiddle.net/QLWn2/), and another that scrolls up and down when the page does (http://jsfiddle.net/ezr6k/). I can't think of any other meaning of "freezing" the header

Comment: Like the behavior in Excel in situations where you have lots of data in a grid formation and you need to keep the headers intact while scrolling horizontally or vertically. [Here's an example of what I'm looking for.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0GH_O4AkTg)

Comment: thats what the first example does. http://jsfiddle.net/QLWn2/ Is this what you're looking for? Is it working here, but just not working on your ASP page?

Comment: Actually its not for me (the Jfiddle example).  The header scrolls up with the rest of the data.

Comment: Using IE version 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: Looks like IE has a problem with jsFiddle. Here's a shared version on Dropbox which works. http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/scroll.html

 make sure to "show all content" when prompted (it has a security issue with jQuery)

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I need just with a scroll bar.  Granted, I viewed it on my phone since dropbox is blocked so the behavior may be different.

Comment: there is a scrollbar ion IE11 in compatibility mode, so I assume its there in IE9 too (IE11 had the same issue with jsFiddle) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/scroll.png

Comment: That's what I thought I had but the best I could come up with is having one fully functional freeze pane in place and then another below it that either scrolled up with the rest of the gridview or left a transparent freeze pane with the header text in place.  That was my main challenge as I couldn't figure out from the code how to tweak it correctly in either CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, or asp.  Every change either made no difference or made it worse.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying this fixes your problem or not

Comment: No, I'm just telling you what the results were from these examples that were the closest to being solved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48626/discussion-between-roryok-and-techie-joe)

Answer (score 2):

While registering scripts, you need to replace the `'GridView1'` with `'" + GridView1.ClientID + "'`. Your methods should look like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "<script>CreateGridHeader('DataDiv','" + GridView1.ClientID +  "', 'HeaderDiv');</script>");
    }
}
protected void cmdClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateGridHeader", "<script>CreateGridHeader('DataDiv','" + GridView1.ClientID + "', 'HeaderDiv');</script>");
}
```

**Explanation:**

With the code you have provided, `GridView1` will be rendered as `MainContent_GridView1`. This will cause javascript error in this line:

```
Row.className = DataGridObj.rows[0].className;
```

So no class name will be assigned to new header row. Therefore no styles will be applied.

Comment: I applied this to my code along with the changes noted in the other Answer.  The results are noted in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two headers because your javascript code copies the header from the `GridView` without removing it. You need to remove the original header row from the `GridView` after you create the new one.

If I create an empty project with a `GridView` and some sample columns, using the styles you provided and NO javascript, the fixed header works. As I scroll up and down the page, the header stays where it should. If this is all you want then remove the javascript and everything will work.

However, I have a feeling what you *really* want is for the header to only scroll when the user scrolls past the `GridView`. That is, it should stay in place on the `GridView` until the top of the browser window is level with the top of the `GridView` and *then* it should freeze.

This is very easy to do in jQuery, which you've already loaded at the top of your page. Here's what you do

CSS

```
.GridViewHeaderStyle
{
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:15px;
    background-color:#507CD1;
    color:black;
    height:40px;

}

.floating{
position:fixed;
top: 40px; /* when floated, we need to add the height of the header to its position , as we will have scrolled past it already. */
}

.padded{
margin-top: 40px; /* once the header position is fixed, the gridview will jump up by 40px, so we need to add this class to make sure it stays put */
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var floating = false;

    $(function () {
        // setup
        // move the header to its own table. simple! 
        var header = $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").find("tr")[0];
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").before($("<table id='floatingheader'>").append(header));

        // when scrolling... 
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            // get position of gridview. 
            var gridposition = $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").offset().top; 
            // get scroll height
            var scrollheight = $(document).scrollTop();

            if(!floating && scrollheight > gridposition){
                $("#floatingheader").addClass("floating"); // float the header
                $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").addClass("padded"); // move the gridview down 40px
                floating = true; // set floating flag to true               
            }

            if(floating && scrollheight < gridposition){
                $("#floatingheader").removeClass("floating"); // remove floating class
                $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>").removeClass("padded"); // remove padding
                floating = false; // set flag to false
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will create a floating header on the `GridView`. Please note, if you have any floating menus at the top of the page you'll need to account for those too.

Comment: I remvoed the Javascript from the code (including the div references) and it just reverts to a normal gridview without scrolling and things as such.  If I leave the div references, then I get the same behavior as before.  One header with a transparent background when scrolled.

Comment: remove your javascript code and replace it with the jquery I gave you in this post, and it will work. I've tested this with a new ASP.NET forms project

Comment: I did with the same results as noted above.

Comment: I started over with a blank page and the header doesn't float but scrolls up with the rest of the gridview.

Comment: Can you please share the entire code of that new page?

Comment: Added it to the bottom of the first post of this thread.  Please note that I get the same results no matter where the jquery code is placed.

Comment: Sorry joe, I meant can you share the final rendered HTML. I can't make that page work without your DataSource. FYI, here's a fiddle of the code working http://jsfiddle.net/ezr6k/

Comment: The rendered code from the fiddle is exactly what happens with my code.  The only difference is that. It's in a formatted box and the code just scrolls up without any floating. Also I don't have the means to give an example that you can connect to or view.

Comment: Done.  Replaced the code at the bottom of the first post in this thread with the rendered HTML.